# Bash: Wait function on multi threading to let only 5 run at a time

Tags: bash, wait

So i have like 100 test cases

```
for test in test_list
do
    sh test &
done
wait
```

But i want 5 to run at a time, rather than all 100 as i end up with brokenpipe errors if i run too many at 1 time.

Is there a way to always have 5 running. So when 1 of the 5 finished, 1 more starts until we complete?

Comment: Use gnu-parallel instead.

Comment: Or `xargs -P`. Or see the many, many duplicates in our knowledgebase.

Comment: BTW, none of this is multithreading -- bash doesn't support multithreading at all. Background processes are whole processes, not threads.